# Jenkins publish over SSH - same commands for all servers

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, publish, jenkins-plugins

I want to use the publish over SSH Jenkins plugin to transfer some files and then run some commands on a target linux machine. That target machine needs to be specified as a build parameter though as we have around 10 potential target machines.

I know I can use parameterized publishing to choose which host to use for the publish over SSH build step, but it seems I have to define every possible server here and duplicate the file set and commands for each one. Is there a way to supply the file set and commands just once and have this apply to all potential target machines?

ie Can the bit in the red circle in this screenshot be specified just once for both servers? And I don't mean just put these commands in a script and transfer that for all servers - I'd still need to put the transfer command in each server configuration block.

Thanks,
Sarah

[image]